# How to set default values in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

Application getting first name,lastname,email address from network login screen through index pages. Those user details getting http...But this option will happen when application working under deployment environment.

I'm working local development environment , so no option to get the user details from http.Please find the below code getting from http to inilize the page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<%= fname %>">
<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="<%= lname %>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<%= email %>">
```

My question is how to set the default values to inilize the all pages ?

Thanks,

Comment: change your getters accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you declare the variable fname, lname, and email, just assign your desired value directly

```
String fname="bill";
String lname="gates";
String email="bil@gates.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass the value which you want to set in input type, like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="Vimal">
<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="Bera">
<input type="hidden" name="useremail" value="abc@abc.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, given a list of three well known cities and a default value in the form backing object, the HTML would be

Town:

```
<input type="radio" name="address.town" value="London">
```

London

```
    <input type="radio" name="address.town" value="Paris"
      checked="checked">
```

Paris

```
<input type="radio" name="address.town" value="New York">
```

NewYork